# Conditional compilation in Perl to not compile a body of code

Tags: debugging, conditional-statements, compilation

I am trying to make some massive changes in a program I wrote some years ago.  Over 600 lines of code.  But I want to test my changes in tiny steps.

When I was coding in C, I would stop the compile process by enclosing most of the code in:

```
#if 0
... my dirty code ...
#endif
```

Is there an equivalent method available in Perl so that I can skip the gazillion errors from the code I haven't yet fixed, so I can clean it up in smaller steps?

With smaller code I simple mass-commented everything I didn't want to compile.  This is too big for that to be practical.

Thanks much for ideas!

Answer (score 0):

OK folks.
People who know me know that if nobody answers my question within a reasonable time (like 17 minutes) I'll eventually figure out *something*.  (Of course, that is no motivation for anyone to answer my question.)  And, honestly, I came by it via another question in this forum, though I can't find it right now to post that URL (to give credit).  Here it is; I've tested it before posting this.

In lieu of the C [prep-processor] directives [#if 0] and [#endif] I specified:

```
=pod
... my still-bad code ...
=cut
```

Not to worry if you already had another POD section in the code.  Just don't run perldoc or pod2pdf on your code, 'cause they gonna barf.

(Now how do I mark this thread "answered"?  I never remember that.)

Comment: The notion of conditional compilation in Perl is still and interesting idea but my reason for asking about it was that I sometimes still think in C and the CPP directives are the way to go in C.  But I can think if other situation in Perl, like code that is OS-dependent and will cause compile errors if jut plunked into your typical if/else conditionals.  But that is for another thread.